# How can i align my form vertically in the center of my form container?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my form vertically and am having trouble, I've tried using display: table-cell and tried using vertical-align: middle property with no luck. I am trying to keep the structure of the page, and I'd prefer the method that someone suggest to me to include a flex-box.

```css
hmtl,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: wheat;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 200px;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-image {
  height: 1200px;
  width: 900px;
}

#main-Form {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="main-image" src="./static/images/30daysreplay-social-media-marketing-3_a7s0MAXhc-unsplash (1).jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-container">
    <form id="main-Form">

      <input type="email" name="email-input" id="">
      <input type="username" name="username" id="">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fix your code and put it in a snippet

Answer (score 1):

```css
#main-Form {
    text-align: center;
}
```